# Coroutine stops when Time.timeScale = 0

Tags: unity

I have a coroutine that smoothly changes a variable in my UI, but when I pause the game, the coroutine pauses too. How can I fix that?

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HUDController : MonoBehaviour {
    public void PauseGame() {
        FreezeTime();
        StartCoroutine(ShowPauseMenu());
    }

    private void FreezeTime() {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }

    private IEnumerator ShowPauseMenu() {
        var pauseMenuCanvasGroup = GameObject.FindWithTag("PauseMenu").GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        var alphaValue = 1f;
        var velocity = 0f;
        var time = 0.15f;

        while (!Mathf.Approximately(pauseMenuCanvasGroup.alpha, alphaValue)) {
            pauseMenuCanvasGroup.alpha = Mathf.SmoothDamp(pauseMenuCanvasGroup.alpha, alphaValue, ref velocity, time);
            yield return null;
        }

        pauseMenuCanvasGroup.alpha = 1; // Since float is not accurate, manually set the alpha to 1
        pauseMenuCanvasGroup.interactable = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue in Unity 5. In my tests, coroutines that `yield return null` or `new WaitForEndOfFrame()` keep humming along just fine when `Time.timeScale = 0` - it's only `yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay)` that pause. Can you confirm what version of Unity you're running?

Comment: @DMGregory 5.2.3f1

Comment: How sure are you that the timescale is the cause? Have you tried to not set the timescale to zero and still run the coroutine?

Comment: Yes, I removed the timescale and it runs just fine

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you run the actual increasing of the number on another thread? Not a unity thread of course... Or another alternative would be to use a different method of pausing the game as opposed to altering the timescale.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is sure to happened because `Mathf.SmoothDamp` uses `Time.deltaTime` in default calculation. When you set `Time.timeScale = 0` then `Mathf.SmoothDamp` won't give the expected value but only first value, repeatedly.

You can further verify by printing alpha value to console, print it in your `while` loop so that you can confirm it by the unlimited logs of same value.

Here is the Documentation on [Mathf.SmoothDamp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html).

You can fix this by passing your own deltaTime to keep it from using its default `Time.deltaTime`. Just add one more parameter to the end of the call:

```
pauseMenuCanvasGroup.alpha = Mathf.SmoothDamp(
  pauseMenuCanvasGroup.alpha, 
  alphaValue, 
  ref velocity, 
  time,
  1000,          // <-- Fifth parameter Optionally allows you to clamp the maximum speed.
  1.0f/30.0f);   // <-- Add a sixth parameter representing your framerate.
```

You can use a function that measures realtime elapsed instead of a constant, if your rendering framerate is variable.

Comment: Dontcha love it when methods do something totally unexpected for completely reasonable (if hard to discern) reasons?

Comment: It doesn't work. It still gives only the first value.

Comment: @Milen yup, that was a little mistyping there, actually that should be the 6th parameter instead of 5th, 5th is the max speed. Check the edits

Comment: @Milen now the code is tested thoroughly :) Give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the situation was like this, and **I SOLVED IT**.
User presses the pause button then some objects goes off (these objects has couroutine(s) ). THIS IS THE PROBLEM.
**I must not turn off those game objects**. The coroutines working fine while the game object is on and when you turn them off every thing is going to be mess.